# Could not build wheels for fbprophet which do not use PEP 517

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, facebook-prophet

I am trying to install **Facebook's** **Prophet** package on my windows system using `pip install fbprophet` command. However, I am getting an error:

> DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for fbprophet which do not use PEP 517.

I am using pip version `20.2.2`, `Python 3.6.8` and all other requirements are satisfied.

I tried searching the issue with `PEP 517`, but couldn't find one. It seems that `fbprophet` package do not use `PIP 517`. I couldn't find a way to disable it or an alternative to install the package.

I also tried using `conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet`, but no luck.

Please let me know what is the issue and how can I resolve it.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: show the command you ran and the full output

Answer (score 0):

You've probably resolved this by now or moved on but I was having a similar issue.  On Windows I was able to install prophet by first running:

```
conda install -c conda-forge compilers
```

to install the appropriate compilers. Then run:

```
conda install -c conda-forge prophet
```

On MacOS I found I needed to install ruby version manager (RVM) to be able to install prophet